# Shapefile for traditional culture areas of the Americas

Tags: geospatial, north-america, south-america

I am searching for a shapefile showing the traditional indigenous culture areas of the Americas.

Here's an example of pretty much exactly what I want (without the plotted tribal names)

http://kids.britannica.com/comptons/art-153006

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but too long for a comment. Thoughts:

- You could use the map itself (pixel-by-pixel analysis) to generate a shapefile.
- Googling several tribe names in quotes (eg, https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mojave%22+%22kaska%22+%22huastec%22+%22blackfeet%22+%22yurok%22+%22chickasaw%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) yields several interesting results, including 2 books and the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_indigenous_peoples_of_the_Americas which has a higher resolution map, but covers a smaller region and does not necessarily agree with your map.
- Doing the above as an image search may also yield potential resources.
- https://www.census.gov/population/www/cen2010/cph-t/t-6tables/TABLE%20%2863%29.csv is probably unhelpful, but poking around on the census.gov site might be useful.
- For a less automated approach, you may want to contact http://www.nmai.si.edu/ -- they have similar maps published online (eg, http://www.nmai.si.edu/education/codetalkers/html/chapter2.html), but I couldn't find any that exactly matched what you wanted (google search: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=992&bih=495&tbm=isch&sa=1&btnG=Search&q=site%3Awww.nmai.si.edu+map)
- A reverse tineye.com search of your image doesn't yield much, but might still be helpful: https://www.tineye.com/search/89cf2f0dca0781afe0dcee5c91e3368a15bf098d/ (alamy.com in particular appears as though they MAY have a vector map of what you need).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions. I had previously done an intensive google search looking for potential leads, but you have suggested some new resources as well. I'm particularly intrigued by generating my own shape file from the map, so I might give that a try. Thanks again.